# Difference between 'take' and 'steal' w.r.t. kidnapping

Tags: meaning, word-choice

As [synonyms](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/kidnap.html) for kidnapping, is there any difference between *Take* and *Steal*. The question raised to me based on two movie titles with almost identical plot:

> **Stolen** (Starring Nicolas Cage) and **Taken** (Starring Liam Neeson).

Comment: I'd say that _as a synonym for kidnapped_, _taken_ seems to be more intuitive. _Stealing_ seems to be something that happens usually to inanimate objects. Apart from that, _take_ has usually not necessarily a negative connotation, whereas _steal_ almost always does (except maybe when you steal a kiss).

Comment: Intuitively for me stolen refers more to the family/community the kidnapped person is stolen from. (The kidnapper has stolen our daughter!) while taken refers to the person that has been kidnapped. (Help, I have been taken away from my family!)

Comment: In general, "steal" is not used for kidnapping.  Probably "stolen" was used for the Cage film because "taken" was already, er, taken.

Answer (score 3):

***Stolen*** has within it's meaning that:

The thing wasn't yours to take.

The object (or being) was (usually) taken in stealth.

With ***"taken"*** the same meaning is forced:

You can *steal* a cookie, (that you weren't supposed to take, when nobody is looking) but, if you *take* a cookie - it may have been offered to you from a plate, in front of a group of people.